# Is this a list initialization or a value initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, initialization, braced-init-list

```
int i {};
```

Is this **List Initialization** or **Value Initialization**?

I can't distinguish them because I can't understand this sentence: a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested braced-init-lists from the link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Answer (score 2):

> Is this List Initialization or Value Initialization?

It is [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> `T object { arg1, arg2, ... };  (1)`
>
> direct-list-initialization (both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered)
>
> 1. initialization of a named variable with a braced-init-list (that is, a possibly empty brace-enclosed list of expressions or nested braced-init-lists)

and the effect on `T` is [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> **Explanation**
>
> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, **if the braced-init-list has no elements,** `T` is *value-initialized*.

And now for the value-initialization of `int`eger you get [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

> **Explanation**
>
> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is a List or Value initialization depends on the object you are initializing. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization:

> If T is a class type that has no default constructor but has a constructor taking std::initializer_list, list-initialization is performed.

So since the object in this case in `int` which does not have a constructor taking a [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) and `int` is not an aggregate type, this is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).